# Why is Console.WriteLine doesn't work outside of VS?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have created WinForms app, when I run it from console (cmd) the console is does not show anything I have logged using Console.WriteLine. It just "hangs" until the program has finished execution. In VS the Output shows a lot of informations, both in Debug and Release mode.

I was hopeing to use console and tracing tool and later be able to determine why something did not work on some outside environment. How to enable that in Console?

Comment: The answer to why, is that the console process is not owned by your WinForms application, therefore `System.Console` does not refer to that console window. I believe you need to call a Windows API in order to get at the console process that launched your app.

Comment: perhaps use log4Net for your logging....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was shocked but doing "MyApp.exe > a.log" has created a log file with information I wanted.

Comment: Don't be shocked; Console.WriteLine just writes to standard output, and you are redirecting standard out to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see if redirecting the console error output like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror.aspx) suggests will work for you. Or you could use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) like @Mitch Wheat suggested

Comment: Thx for suggestion, but I was able to hack it another way :)